# How can I determine the system requirements of my APP?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Well, I have a application which somehow *requires* some system resources, but how do I determine all the needs of the application? How do companies which release software and games know you need a 1.5 ghz processor? And what is the fastest way to let my visual basic 2010 app use the maximum amount of memory it will ever use?

Comment: The application is made with Visual Basic 2010, so vb.net ;o lemme change tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most developers make an estimate based on experience of what is required to run the software.

Improving on that method involves doing actual testing of the application under different hardware environments which requires multiple test machines. This is a whole subject in itself.

The fastest way to use the maximum amount of memory depends on how your program works but you have not provided any specific details.